# One table referencing multiple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with users that I want to reference 3 other tables of different types. To make it simple, let's say table x is of type 0, y of type 1 and z of type 2.

In tables x, y, z I thought of adding a column that will have the default value its type, so these tables are gonna have their PK on an ID and a column with their default value.

After inserting values in x, y or z I want to insert the id and type in the users table.

I created a unique constraint on `Id` and `Type` for each of these 3 tables. The problem is I can't add 3 FKs on `Users` to reference the `Id` and `Type` for each of the tables. What solution could I use to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code to reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want foreign key references from users to the other three tables, using an "id" and "type" column.  Here is one method:

In the `Users` table, you can add three computed columns for types:

```
alter table users add column id_x as (case when type = 'x' then id end) persisted;
alter table users add column id_y as (case when type = 'y' then id end) persisted;
alter table users add column id_z as (case when type = 'z' then id end) persisted;
```

Then you can add the foreign key constraints:

```
alter table users add constraint fk_users_x on x(id_x);
alter table users add constraint fk_users_y on y(id_y);
alter table users add constraint fk_users_z on z(id_z);
```